# CLion: Can't include Math.h

Tags: c, clion, math.h

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(fms C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(fms main.c fms.c fms.h fms_data.c)

target_link_libraries(fms m)
```

The following is one of the compiler errors:

> C:\Users\Holland\CLionProjects\fms\fms.c(27): error C2065: "M_PI":
> nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner

Comment: Are you linking the math library also? with a GCC toolchain, you usually need to add `-lm` to link `ibm` which is the math library.

Comment: Based on that file path, you're using Windows. `M_PI` isn't defined in the usual Windows C headers.

Comment: You don't do that with CMake, fms.c is missing `#include <math.h>`. m is specific to GCC, don't link it for MSVC.